# How is a webpage forced refreshed, such as when using some CLI tools?

Tags: reactjs, webserver, page-refresh

I noticed when using the React CLI development tool, I can open up the site http://localhost:3000/ and when I change any code such as code inside App.js, the webpage is automatically refreshed to reflect the content.

I thought at first it might be the `npm start` script triggering Google Chrome to refresh the page (such as using Bash `open http://localhost:3000/`, but if I open up multiple pages with http://localhost:3000/ and even with MS Edge looking at the page http://localhost:3000/, any change to the source code also force all pages to be refreshed.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, it is done by [HMR: Hot Module Replacement](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/):

> HMR Server uses websockets to inform the HMR Runtime that it needs an update. HMR Runtime requests those updates over HTTP .

Here is a [webpack guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/) and a [blog post](https://www.javascriptstuff.com/understanding-hmr/).